# Flow firing twice

Tags: visual-workflow

I am building a Flow to send an email when certain fields on an object (part of a managed package) are changed.

This will typically fire when a user interacts with the object (via a custom page that is part of the managed package).

The flow is firing twice. I reckon because the managed package has some triggers running, which sets certain fields on the object, thereby starting the flow again.

The basic config:

- The flow starts when the Object is Updated. Criteria: `[Field] isChanged == true`
- Optimised for Actions and Related Records
- Run "Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements" (forced because it is using an `isChanged` criteria)
- Send email (Email Alert)

What I have tried:

- Having a custom checkbox on the object, which is tested for in the entry criteria. It is set (`=true`) when first run, and cleared (`=false`)by a separate Flow a minute later. This doesn't work. I guess the Flow runs twice before the flag is set??

  - (I also tried a Scheduled Path on the same Flow to clear the flag, but it didn't allow me to save it, as it seems incompatible with the run "Every time a record is updated and meets the criteria", and therefore incompatible with an `isChanged` criterion. Error:  "This flow has a scheduled path with a time source based on when a record is created or updated. Configure the flow to run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements.")
- Testing for the field being the same value. i.e. not just `isChanged == true` but `Record.[field (number)] == RecordPrior.[field (number)]`

I'm out of ideas. Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details and clarifications.  You selected  Actions/Related Records for your flow mode, right?  Do you expect the user to manually change a field, or some import/integration to make the changes and fire the Flow?  Please [edit] your post.

Comment: did you set `Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements option for When to Run the Flow for Updated Records.` ?

Comment: Thanks both - I have added those details requested.

Comment: @DavidCheng wondering if you have any thoughts having added the details?